# Simple way to set Button Active Color in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Ive been looking around for methods to change active state on Button click. I have 4 buttons when clicked the reposition my scroll view as programmed.

I am trying to set the background color to fade a bit if clicked. Im able to set the background color but it stays the same faded color when another is clicked. It doesnt return to an inactive state.

Any simple way to acheive this onckick button behavior globally?

heres my button click func's:

```
@IBAction func tab1(sender: UIButton)

{

    slScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), animated: true)

    tab1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    tab2.selected = false
    tab3.selected = false
}


@IBAction func tab2(sender: UIButton)
{
    slScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, 650.0), animated: true)

    tab2.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    tab1.selected = false
    tab3.selected = false

}


@IBAction func tab3(sender: UIButton) {
    slScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, 1370.0), animated: true)

    tab3.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    tab1.selected = false
    tab2.selected = false
    }
```

Comment: So you have 4 buttons, When you click 1, it fades... Then when u click the second button...this fades, but the first goes back to original color.. Is this what you are trying to achieve? Some code would help as well.

Comment: They change color but dont return to the original color when the active button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

First, create an `IBOutletCollection` (or four separate outlets) to the buttons. Then create an `IBAction` method and set **all four** buttons to fire it when tapped. In the method, do the background fade animation on the button that fired the action (which is passed into the handler as its `sender` argument, then reset the states of the other outlet buttons.

The way I would code it:

```
// Outlet to all of the buttons. ctrl+drag each button to this outlet.
@IBOutletCollection buttons = [UIButton]()

// Set *all* of the buttons to fire this method.
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject!) {
    (sender as? UIButton).backgroundColor = <whatever>

    for button in buttons.filter({ $0 != sender }) {
        button.backgroundColor = <default>
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my idea but i dont know ehat method to use to return to state.

Comment: Buttons have numerous settable (e.g. `enabled`, `selected`, `highlighted`) properties inherited from the UIControl class. If you want to get back to the "normal" state, then set `selected` to `false`.

Comment: i tried your method but if the other buttons are clicked the initial one doesnt go back to the unselected color which is a system color. i added my button methods to my post btw

Comment: Ah, I see. You're changing the state, but `backgroundColor` isn't associated with any particular state, so it stays set even after a different button is clicked. You need to set the unselected buttons' background colors to the default value in each of those handler methods.